# Coolant leak passenger side on floor

Tags: coolant, dodge, leak, journey

2009 Journey has coolant on floor of garage on passenger side.  Car doesn’t overheat but had to add coolant to the reservoir.    Mechanic can’t find leak.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is it actually a coolant leak or is it just moisture leaking onto the floor?

Comment: If it is coolant your heater core is leaking and needs replaced, if it clear water then the drain for your AC box is clogged.

Comment: @user37934 - I see you now have a regular account and appreciate the edit. If you'd like to take ownership of this question, please have your accounts merged by following the directions [at this link](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Taste it , glyco will be sweet ( don't swallow ) . If not sweet ,it is water condensate. Yes , I have done it a few times and never died.

Answer (score 1):

If its really coolant, then heater core is probably leaking.  Surprised your mechanic can't find that.

If its just water (even dirty water), there should be a drain (if you've ever seen a car drip water on a hot day with the AC on) have your mechanic verify the drain is clear.

Both are typically on passenger side of car.